# Update Dynamics CRM 2011 to RU14

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I have CRM 2011 running on RU11. I updated it to RU14 but I get the following error when I browse the organization from the deployment manager:

> An error has occurred.
>
> Try this action again. If the problem continues, check the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Community for solutions or contact your organization's Microsoft Dynamics CRM Administrator. Finally, you can contact Microsoft Support.

I also restarted the computer but after the update but that didn't make a difference. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the update failed, I'd restore the backup and try again (keeping track of what happens, logs, event viewer...)

Comment: That was it, I reinstalled it and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the update failed, restore a backup and repeat the installation.